# ArcGIS SDK use distanceBetween with Android.location

Tags: android, arcgis, point

I am using ArcGis Sdk to manage geographic cards on my Android application, and I want to know how to calculate the shortest distance between 2 geometries. 
I tried with Two multipoint, I worked perfectly, but when I used my location returned via

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Point geomMyPosition = new Point(location.getLongitude(),location.getLatitude(), SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
double minDistance = GeometryEngine.distanceBetween(geomMyPosition,buildingGeom);
```

I get this :

```
UncaughtException: com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Invalid argument
                         at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.jni.CoreGeometryEngine.nativeDistance(Native Method)
                         at com.esri.arcgisruntime.internal.jni.CoreGeometryEngine.f(SourceFile:160)
```

AnyOne have an idea about how to resolve this ? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the two Geometries hadn't same Spatial reference.
but unifying it, it worked like a charm.